# Can execute map fun inside a map fun of two different rdd generate data shuffle in Spark Cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Learning Distributed and Cloud Programming through Scala lang and Spark, I have a doubt.
I'm executing in a cluster of 3vm and if I have 2 spark rdd and I apply the following code, when I run `rdd2.map` function, does it imply any shuffle over data ?

```
var data= for {
    row <- rdd1
    id = row._1
    word = row._2
    x = rdd2.map( keyword => {
       (id.toInt, keyword, (if ( keyword == word ) 1 else 0))
        } )
 } yield {
    (id, word, x) 
 }
```

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to _do_ here? Do you realize, that this is trying to replicate the _entire second rdd_ for each row of the first rdd. Even if this worked, it hardly seems useful. Luckily, it does not: you can't nest transformations inside other transformations. I think, it would help, if you took a step back and started with explaining what it is you are actually trying to achieve, perhaps, showing some sample inputs, and the output you want to get from it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no shuffle over data with `map` operations:

> Operations which can cause a shuffle include repartition operations
> like repartition and coalesce, ‘ByKey operations (except for counting)
> like groupByKey and reduceByKey, and join operations like cogroup and
> join.

[Source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#background)